# Location of package_data directory with Python setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have some images that I want to distribute with my Python module.  I'm using setuptools and installing with pip.

```
setup(
    ...
    package_data={
        'images': glob.glob('images/*'),
    },
    ...
)
```

I see this output during the install:

```
hard linking images/my_icon.ico -> my_package-0.0.1/images
```

But I can't actually *find* this images folder.  I can't find a folder called my_package-0.0.1 either.  I have site_packages/my_package-0.0.1.dist-info/ and site_packages/my_package, but no my_package-0.0.1. I've been through the documentation and I'm still pretty confused.

I'm trying to understand several things.

1. Where does package_data go?
2. How do I access package_data from within my Python code?
3. Is this the correct way to include my image files, and if not, what is?

Answer (score -2):

You should have your files in a folder of your choosing, i.e. images, that should be located under the 'Static' folder in your python project folder. Another thing to look into is a requirements.txt file.